# How to push a new object into array in Js using Php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object, push

I have an object in Php, so I need to push it into array in Js which is located in another file called 'db.js'.
Object->

```
$datae = array(
 'img'  => 'push-ups.webp',
 'videoname'=> $name,
 'name' => $_POST['name'],
 'text' => $_POST['description']
);
```

db.js inner ->

```
let dataGoods = [{
    "img": "push-ups.webp",
    "videoname": "igorBaitenko.mp4",
    "name": "Push-ups",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
}, {
    "img": "push-ups.webp",
    "videoname": "igorBaitenko.mp4",
    "name": "Push-ups",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
}];
```

I've tried this code to append object into array ->

```
$inp = file_get_contents('db.js');
$tempArray = json_decode($inp);
array_push($tempArray, json_decode($datae));

$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
file_put_contents('db.js', $jsonData );
```

But there was some mistakes, so I need your help please.

Comment: I really don't think pushing the code from php to the js file is a good idea. If you need to pass something from php it's better to render it in the HTML to a global variable (`window.state` for example) and then read it using JS.

Comment: PHP's `array_push` only pushes values, not keys. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php, user contributions for some solitions.

Answer (score 0):

You made two mistakes:

1. The `db.js` contains a JavaScript snippet, but you pass it to `json_decode()` as if it were JSON. You have to "convert" JavaScript to JSON, or, you can save `$tempArray` as JSON into `db.json` and load it from `db.js`.
2. You use `array_push($tempArray, json_decode($datae))`, but `$datae` is an array. You can push it just like: `$tempArray[] = $datae`.